# How to constrain the size of a child flex element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm facing an issue that I'm trying to solve using flex boxes and without a hack.

I have a list of item.

Each item is a row composed by :

- an icon element with a fixed width
- a content element with adaptative width
- a buttons container element with fixed width

My content element has two lines with different styles (ID and description of the item). The problem occures when the description is too long, the content element become too wide.

HTML:

```
<div class="column">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row_icon"></div>
    <div class="row_content">
      <div class="row_content_itemName">Item 1 name</div>
      <div class="row_content_itemDesc">Item 1 description</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_buttons"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row_icon"></div>
    <div class="row_content">
      <div class="row_content_itemName">Item 2 name</div>
      <div class="row_content_itemDesc">Item 2 verrrrrrrryyyyy looooonnnnggg description</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_buttons"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.column {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

.row_icon {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.row_buttons {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: orange;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.row_content {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.row_content_itemDesc {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3LqyLsd4/4/)

I'd like to make that second line displayed without wraping and with an ellipsis. Any idea how I could solve this ?

EDIT :

Thanks to mlegg comment I solved this issue by adding overflow: hidden; on the parent container.

[Solved jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3LqyLsd4/5/)

Comment: put  overflow: hidden; in the .row_content line of your css